# Do I need a custom converter for this?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

From viewing the source code that this code makes it looks like `itemValue` generate the value based on the objects `toString()` method. So `bean.question.categories` can't be an arraylist containing categories....at least it does not work. Do I need to make my own converter in order to have this working?

```
<h:selectManyMenu value="#{bean.question.categories}" id="questionCategories">
    <f:selectItems value="#{categoryValuesManager.categories}" var="category"
                   itemValue="#{category}" itemLabel="#{category.description}"/>
</h:selectManyMenu>
```

The question entity also has a bi-directional many-to-many relationship with the category entity and it gives me headace!
 Because; when making a new question instance the `categories`property of that instance is null, right? So I need to assign a empty `ArrayList<Category>` to it. Then, do I need to loop over each item in that arraylist and assign an arraylist with the one question instance on the category side too?

Comment: `bean.question.categories`... what is `categories`? is it a list? Can't be a list.

Comment: Yes it is a list? Why can't it be that?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, it's a select-many, I was thinking about select-one.

Comment: So do you get any error when you try to run that?

Comment: Yes, it says the value is not valid

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to present a list of categories stored in database in JSF correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202569/how-to-present-a-list-of-categories-stored-in-database-in-jsf-correctly), asked by yourself.

Comment: That is no bi-directional manytomany relationship.

Comment: So, how does that matter? The converter is applied to every single item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to make my own converter in order to have this working?

I think you have to create your own `Converter`. JSF cannot automatically convert a string to your `Entity` object.

> Do I need to loop over each item in that arraylist and assign an arraylist with the one question instance on the category side too?

If you successfully created a `Converter` that can convert a `String` input to the corresponding `Category` object, your `<h:selectManyMenu>` will give you a `List<Category>`. Then I think you can assign it directly to the question's `categories` property. You will still have to loop over your `categories` List to bind the `Question` entity to each and every of them.

Comment: But do since it is bi-directional, do I need to loop over the list of categories and assign the question also?